# How do I cache the current authenticated user?

Tags: php, laravel

## Description

In my situation, I don't have a `users` table locally, but I have an api that will provide me a list of users.

---

## getUsers()

I modify my `getUsers()` for my `Auth::user()` in `app/Auth/ApiUserProvider.php`

```
protected function getUsers()
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, env('API_HOST') . 'vse/accounts');

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response['data'];
}
```

---

## Issue

Each time, I used `Auth::user()` in my code. It makes a call to my API `.../vse/accounts`
It effects a lot of latency in my application.

---

## Try#1

**Session**

```
protected function getUsers()
{

    if(Session::has('user')){
        return Session::get('user');
    }else{
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, env('API_HOST') . 'vse/accounts');
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        curl_close($ch);
        $user = $response['data'];
        Session::put('user',$user);
        return $user;
    }

}
```

**Result**

It takes 2 seconds longer.

---

How do I solve this?

Should I start using cache? If so, how do I modify what I have to do something like that? Should I store it in the session?

Comment: Try this: http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5

Comment: I already did the custom auth, I was trying to cache my `Auth::user()` object, so I don't have to hit my API all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
protected function getUsers() {
    $minutes = 60;
    $user = Cache::remember('user', $minutes, function () {
        //your api stuff
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, env('API_HOST') . 'vse/accounts');
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response['data'];
    });
         return $user;
}
```

this should work

> Sometimes you may wish to retrieve an item from the cache, but also
>   store a default value if the requested item doesn't exist
>   -laravel docs

you will get the user from the cache or, if he don't exist, retrieve user from the api and add him to the cache

Comment: Quick question, so Session won't work ? Ok. I'll try catch.

Comment: i THINK this would be more efficient

Comment: Okay. Fair enough. :)

Comment: if{ this worked for you/or this is what you are looking for, dont forget to tick it as answered} else{i hope you find the right solution}

Comment: I'll accept it if it solve my problem so far upvote for trying. :)

Comment: I update my post with cached try#2, can you check to see if i did it right. I am close.

Comment: i edited my answer, you should return the $value  , i changed it to $user for better readability, this should work

Comment: Ohh okay. Got it. Let me see if all of these, improve my loading time. Then, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: brw i just fixed an issue the return has to be before the  }); closing brackets

Comment: You sure return $user; is not after the `});` ?

Comment: ah wait i made a mistake , il fix answer (when you return response[data] the $user variable will have the data(from cache if available or from api) then you return the $user (the return of the php method) and try dd($user before the return to check if you have data)

Comment: Your updated answer works, I can log-in like normal now. :)

Comment: Thanks for your assistant mate. I wish there is a friend request in stackoverflow, so I can add nice people like you. :)